# How to add a precompiled library in autotools?

Tags: automake, autotools

I have a precompiled shared object that I need to distribute with the package I'm building, how do I get automake to copy the shared object to the lib/ folder where it places all of the rest of the shared objects that it compiles during the compilation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old workaround seems to be still working

```
mylibdir = $(libdir)
dist_mylib_SCRIPTS = libxxx.so
```